# Yahoo Placefinder API and cURL/wget

Tags: json, http, curl, wget, yahoo-api

I'm trying to make requests to the Yahoo Placefinder API using a script I wrote, and I'd like it to return JSON. However, all the requests send back XML. That being said, when I run the same script in my browser, I get JSON data as expected. Here are my requests:

```
wget http://where.yahooapis.com/geocode?location=San+Francisco,+CA&flags=J&appid=yourappid

curl http://where.yahooapis.com/geocode?location=San+Francisco,+CA&flags=J&appid=yourappid
```

Any help is much appreciated. This is pretty frustrating, and seems like it should be easy to fix!

Comment: I dun getting JSON when `curl -X GET "http://where.yahooapis.com/geocode?location=San+Francisco,+CA&flags=J"`, are you missing the parameters?

Comment: That fixed it! Was missing the curl parameters. Put this as an answer and I'll mark it as answered!

Answer (score 2):

You might also try using Placefinder through [YQL](http://developer.yahoo.com/yql/) (Yahoo Query Language). It offers both XML and JSON output and gives you some more flexibility for mashups with other services.

Here's a sample call:

[`select * from geo.placefinder where text="sfo"`](http://developer.yahoo.com/yql/console/?q=select%20%2a%20from%20geo.placefinder%20where%20text%3D%22sfo%22)